# CSS rules for multiple attribute values: button and input behaves differently

Tags: css

In the example below, I am applying the same rules to `submit` and `button` elements, but when rendered, they are behaving differently. The `button` element behaves as expected; however, the `input` element is green by default even when there is no hovering, and does not change colour at all on hover. I have set up a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/D5WZ5/

CSS:

```
input[type="submit"],[type="button"]
{
    background-color:blue;
}

input[type="submit"],[type="button"]:hover
{
    background-color:green;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<input type="button" value="Button" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/D5WZ5/2/)

Change your CSS to:

```
input[type="submit"],[type="button"]{
    background-color:blue;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover,[type="button"]:hover{
    background-color:green;
}
```

You hadn't also applied the `:hover` selector to your `input` element

Comment: @Karnivaurus - no worries, dont forget to mark answers as accepted if they satisfy you so as to help future visitors to SO